# Why are my new windows forms being forced into a Builder namespace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm in the process of working on a Windows Forms project in Visual Studio. There are around 15 different forms at the moment, each of which are in namespace foo. For example:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace foo
    {
        public FormSelectProject() : Form
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ...
    }
```

This works fine. When I created a new form today, instead of using namespace foo, the default was namespace Builder. So:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Builder
    {
        public FormCreateFeature() : Form
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ...
    }
```

If I change the Builder namespace to foo, I get the error CS0103 `The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context.`

I can work around this by just adding `using foo;` at the top of the form, but I'm just curious as to why this is happening, especially since other forms are still loading fine.

Comment: There are at least two files for that form. You can't change _just one_ of them.

Comment: @mjwills Ok, so I realize now that the FormCreateFeature.Designer.cs file was using namespace Builder as well. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yep, that is what I meant.

Comment: If the root (default) namespace was "foo" and is now "Builder" then you made that change in the project properties "Application" tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @mjwills above. I had only changed the namespace in the FormCreateFeature.cs file and not in the FormCreateFeature.Designer.cs file as well. Changing both fixed the issue.